# How to delete an an optional entity in Hibernate without deleting the owning entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate appears to enforce mandatory relationships between entities. However, I have a `User` entity and a `Portfolio` entity. Each `User` can have 0 or 1 portfolios (but each `Portfolio` must have a `User`). As a result, a `User` should be able to delete a `Portfolio` without deleting the `User` entity. So far, I am unable to achieve this outcome. Instead, if a `User` deletes his/her `Portfolio`, the `User` also gets deleted.

How can I modify my annotations to achieve the desired outcome?

-User

```
/*
 * Each User can have a Portfolio with many Accounts. 
*/
@Entity
@Check(constraints = "LENGTH(TRIM(username)) > 0 &&"
        + " LENGTH(TRIM(username)) > 0 &&"
        + " LENGTH(TRIM(email)) > 0 &&"
        + " LENGTH(TRIM(password)) > 10")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Nationalized
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @Nationalized
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    private String salt;

    @Nationalized
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Portfolio portfolio;

    // Not showing constructors, getters, or setters
  
}
```

-Portfolio

```
/*
 * An Portfolio is a collection of accounts.
 */
@Entity
public class Portfolio {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "portfolio", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    // Not showing constructors, getters, or setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the cascade configured in your Portfolio entity.

By putting cascade = CascadeType.ALL you are instructing hibernate that when a Portfolio is deleted, it should delete the related User on cascade.

In this scenario, you can remove the cascade in that relationship, and keep the cascade in the User.portfolio relationship, because you want the Portfolio to be deleted when the User is deleted.

Comment: if I remove the cascade type, then deleting the portfolio doesn't delete it's entity relations. For example, a portfolio can have many accounts. I have tried   `portfolioRepository.deleteById(id);` and `portfolioRepository.delete(portfolio);` but neither actually delete anything related to the portfolio (e.g. accounts and individual investments).

Comment: An `Account` has a foreign key relationship with `Portfolio`, so how can I delete the `Portfolio` and have the list of `Account` also deleted?

Comment: The cascade behavior is per relationship, not per entity. You can delete the cascade attribute in the Portfolio.user relationship, but keep it in the Portfolio.accounts relationship.

Comment: doesn't this mean that, if an account gets deleted, the portfolio gets deleted? What is need is for a User to exist if the portfolio gets deleted, but all related accounts should get deleted. However, if an account gets deleted, the portfolio can still exist because a portfolio can have many accounts.

Comment: No, the cascade applies only in the direction of the attribute. If you put the cascade in Portfolio.accounts, when a Portfolio is deleted its accounts are deleted. If you don't put the cascade on Account.portfolio, when an Account is deleted its portfolio is not deleted.

Comment: So said another way, setting Cascade.All (for example) marks the current object for deletion whenever the entity that it references is deleted. Is that accurate? 

The only way I’ve gotten this to work so far is to get the current user and set the user’s portfolio to null. I can see hibernate generate the delete statements properly.

Comment: Cascade.ALL means all operations (save, update, delete, etc) are propagated to the target entity in the specific relationship, it does not mean all relationships. Think this way, the cascade is directional, it applies to a specific attribute, in that specific direction. No matter if you have bidirectional relationships (mappedBy), cascade applies only to the direction of the attribute where you use it. So in your case, I would put cascade in User.portfolio, Portfolio.accounts, and don't put in Portfolio.user and Account.portfolio.

Comment: How come deleteById(id) is not working then? The only way I can get hibernate to create actual delete statements is simply to set the attribute to null and have the orphanRemoval = true annotation.